# Question on the proof of the continuity of an inverse function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The Theorem given in the book is: A mapping $f$ of a metric space $Y$ is continuous on $X$ if and only if
$f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ for every open set $V$ in $Y$

The proof given is:[image]

I'm not sure whats happening after "Since V is open". Namely, how the $d_y$ and $d_x$ functions are created and how they relate to the delta epsilons. I figured this was using the delta epsilon definition of continuity and tried to compare it to that but couldn't come to a conclusion. Any explanation of that part of the proof would be helpful. (The second paragraph can probably be ignored for the purpose of my question; I just included it to give the whole proof)

Comment: Heuristically, start with the definition of open set in a metric space and think of it this way: because $V$ is open in the metric space $Y$, you can draw an open ball around $f(p)$ and shrink it as small as you want and it'll still be in $V$. Because $f$ is continuous, that means if the size of the ball $B_{\epsilon}$ around $f(p)$ is fixed, you can draw a corresponding open ball  $B_{\delta}$ around $p$ in $X$, and shrink that ball until $f(x)$ is in $B_{\epsilon}$ for every $x$ in $B_{\delta}$. Therefore, every $p$ in $f^{-1}(V)$ is an interior point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was helpful for understanding whats going on in the proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V$ is open and $f(p)\in V$, since balls are basic open sets in the metric space $Y$, one finds some ball $B_{\epsilon}(f(p))$ that containing $f(p)$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(f(p))\subseteq V$. This means that for all $y\in B_{\epsilon}(f(p))$, then $y\in V$. But $y\in B_{\epsilon}(f(p))$ means that $d_{Y}(f(p),y)<\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you explain what the term $d_y$(f(p),y) represents; I understood everything until that term. I'm not sure why you would put f(p) and y in the set. Also, I'm not missing any notation here right, $d_y$ is just arbitrary notation?

Comment: $d_{Y}$ means the metric in the space $Y$, and $d_{Y}(f(p),y)$ is the distance between the points $f(p)$ and $y$.